# KeyListener won't work even though panel prints

Tags: java, keylistener

I have the following code (I do `frame.add(new LevelPanel())` in my main method that extends `JFrame`. For some reason, this code for the `KeyListener` is exactly how it is for other people and yet it doesn't recognize anything.

It should at least print out "Got here" when I press a key (and it doesn't). The code does print the panel, but the panel has no reaction to any of the keys I press.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/*
 * Items represent the things in the level that can be picked up.
 * Subclasses: Gem
 * 
 * @author Tim Ochsner
 * @version 1.0 11/18/2012
 */

public class LevelPanel extends JPanel {
private Game game;
private Level level;
private Player player;
private char[][] table =
        {{'p', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f'},
        {'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f'},
        {'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f'},
        {'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f'},
        {'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f'},
        {'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f'},
        {'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f'},
        {'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f'},
        {'w', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f'},
        {'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f'},
        {'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f'},
        {'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'w', 'f'},
        {'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f'},
        {'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f'},
        {'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f'}};

public LevelPanel(Game game)
{
    this.game = game;
    player = game.getPlayer();
    level = new Level(game, table);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    addKeyListener(new ArrowListener());

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    level.draw(g);
}

public class ArrowListener implements KeyListener {

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Got here");
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            if (!(player.getCol() == 14) && level.getTileLayout()[player.getRow() + 1][player.getCol()].isPassable()) {
                System.out.println("Got here");
                player.move(player.getRow() + 1, player.getCol());
                table[player.getRow()][player.getCol()] = 'f';
                table[player.getRow() + 1][player.getCol()] = 'p';
            }
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Got here");

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Got here");         
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyListener` is a fickle mistress, I would recommend that you avoid them in favor of [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

`KeyListener` will only fire an event if 1- The component is focusable and 2- the component has focus.  Key bindings allow you to get around this restriction.

If you MUST use a `KeyListener`, first call `setFocusable(true)` on your `LevelPanel`, followed by `requestFocusInWindow`.

Comment: @user1852433: but do the smart thing. Scrap  your KeyLIstener code and use Key Bindings (as MP states in his answer -- 1+). In the long run,  you'll be grateful that you did.

Comment: @user1852433 should also add, Key bindings generally produce reusable and cleaner code in the long run ;)